# Bad rendering persian/arabic font in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, html

sometimes, when refreshing a web page in chrome, persian/arabic fonts didn't render correctly like below image:
[image: Bad rendering font]

i used this code in my page:

```
@font-face { 
    font-family: 'Persian'; 
    src: 
        url(../fonts/persian.eot?#) format('eot'),
        url(../fonts/persian.woff2) format('woff2'),
        url(../fonts/persian.woff) format('woff'); 
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried generating the relevant CSS and fonts via [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)?

Comment: You should also verify that you've set the page's character set to Unicode (usually utf-8 is good enough).

Comment: @MattMaclennan i converted my fonts with this site, but the problem still exist :(

Comment: @TiesonT. Yes, i used <meta charset="utf-8" /> in my html page .